# how to check only 4 or 16 numeric digits in the input box using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am creating a web page where I have a input text field in which I want to check only 4 or 16 numeric digit

How can i make it using jquery?

Comment: do you mean that you want to be sure the user only ENTERS 4 or 16 digits?  Or that you have to search the text field for a 4 or 16 digit numeric value?  Could you clarify a little?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of :

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    var val = $('#someinput').val();
    if(/^(\d{4}|\d{16})$/.test(val) == false) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery validator:
[Source](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength#length)

```
$("#myform").validate({   rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4,
      maxLength:16
    }   } });
```

Comment: this checks 4 to 16 digit, but rajat said 4 or 16 digit

Comment: True, I didn't read the specs well enough. But OTOH, an input field which requires an input with four or sixteen digits doesn't, IMHO, make for a great ui and should be split into two fields. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

if your looking for jquery validation this methode will help you

jquery validation(http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("textfield", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(\d{4}|\d{16})$/ i.test(value);
        }, "<br>You must enter 4 digit or 16-digit");
```

Please clarify your question !